# From batch file execution some commands are not getting executed

Tags: batch-file

Created a batch file with following lines

```
pyenv install 3.8.0
pyenv local 3.8.0
pyenv rehash
```

and executed in command line
observed first line executed successfully after that
next lines are not picked in command line

[image: Command line image]

Comment: Is `pyenv` a batch file?

Comment: **1.** ```Call "%UserProfile%\.pyenv\pyenv-win\bin\pyenv.bat" install 3.8.0```, **2.** ```Call "%UserProfile%\.pyenv\pyenv-win\bin\pyenv.bat" local 3.8.0```, **3.** ```"%UserProfile%\.pyenv\pyenv-win\bin\pyenv.bat" rehash```.

Comment: @Magoo pyenv is a batch file

Comment: @Compo tried as u said but only first line got executed not remaining ones

Comment: What Compo said *should* work - simply prefix each of your three lines with `call `. Without actually seeing `pyenv.bat`, it's difficult to tell - and I'll warrant it's not a short file. Another possibility is `start /wait "" ` as a prefix for each line...